# Python ClassMethod Error: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, class, methods, static

I made a function **ClassAttribsToDict** which would convert user-defined attributes in a class to dictionary.

```
def ClassAttribsToDict(myclass):
  return dict(filter(lambda (k,v): not k.startswith("__"),vars(myclass).items()))

class AnimalEnums(object):
  dog = 0
  cat = 2
  horse = 7
```

Executing the function on a class name converts it into dictionary

```
>>> ClassAttribsToDict(AnimalEnums)
{'horse': 7, 'dog': 0, 'cat': 2}
```

Now I tried to make a base class and include this method **ClassAttribsToDict** as a **classmethod**:

```
class EnumBase(object):
  @classmethod
  def ClassAttribsToDict(myclass):
    return dict(filter(lambda (k,v): not k.startswith("__"),vars(myclass).items()))
```

However when I try to call ClassAttribsToDict function on class EnumBase, I get following error:

```
>>> EnumBase.ClassAttribsToDict(AnimalEnums)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ClassAttribsToDict() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Further, I want to inherit EnumBase class to make them behave as enumeration as follows:

```
class LanguagesEnum(EnumBase):
  EN = 0
  CN = 1
  FR = 2
  DE = 3
```

And expect to convert class attributes to dictionary

```
>>> LanguagesEnum.ClassAttribsToDict(LanguagesEnum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, by adding `@classmethod` you're making your `def ClassAttribsToDict`'s first parameter always be the class it's included in (which would be `EnumBase` in this case). It's similar to how your "regular" methods in class always takes starts with `self`, except it takes the class itself instead of a class instance.

So when you're calling EnumBase.ClassAttribsToDict(AnimalEnums), it's actually acting like ClassAttribsToDict(EnumBase, AnimalEnums), from the method's perspective (thus it thinks it's got 2 arguments).

anyway : changing to `def ClassAttribsToDict(cls, myclass):` will very likely work out for you.

(Also a side note - according to PEP8 you should probably switch to class_attribs_to_dict for methods, classes can stay CapsWords style)